# Create a basic simple web app in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a basic web app in zend Framework 1 and in around the web I mostly saw the tutorial for installation of ZF2 or latest.

I have followed the instruction from [Zend quickstart](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) and I have downloaded the .tar.gz and extracted to my localhost and when I run the app appending /public or /public/index.php it shows the error like below.

[image]

Please let me know if I am going in a wrong way or probably instruction to start in a correct way.

Comment: Had you checked for Zend library under library/ folder ?

Comment: What web server are you running? Look at the error logs of said server. Why are you using Zend 1 to begin with instead of more up-to-date versions?

Comment: I am on unbuntu machine using apache server, I had to add Zend library in my project's library folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add library into your project, Please check the Zend/ folder under library/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure that you have zend framework install, if not install by typing

  `sudo apt-get install zend-framework`
- Then go to your project folder
  `cd /path/to/your/project`
- Then go to library folder of the project `cd /path/to/your/project/library`
- Then run the command `ln -s /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend`
- Restart your server `service apache2 restart`

and thats it.